# How to match part of the string with other string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have 2 strings, i need to match both the string.
Its bit tricky as the last part of the string should match with the first part of another string.

I have tried with string.Contains() method but not successful because there can be n number of subfolders in both the strings

Example :

```
var string1 = @"C:/GII/gii_db/DownTime/EMEA";
var string2 = @"DownTime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";
```

Here the part **DownTime/EMEA** in both the string should match.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to match? Can you give examples of positive matches and negative ones?

Comment: I need to match the last part of first string DownTime/EMEA with second string.

Comment: Now, you've written `/`, but I think you want `\\` - not that it affects the question. Valid C# code is always preferred.

Comment: Do you want the longest match? Any match? What happens when you have a string
`"abcbc"` matching with `"bcbcd"`? Both `"bc"` and `"bcbc"` are correct matches.

Comment: Also, are these any "strings" or specifically paths that you're matching? If they're paths, does `"A/B/N"` matched with `"B/Name/irrelevant"` result in a match of `"B/N"` or are you only interested in full tokens (so only if the first path was `"A/B/Name"` would it result in a match of `"B/Name"`)?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var string1 = @"C:/GII/gii_db/DownTime/EMEA";
var string2 = @"DownTime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";

bool is_match =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, (string1.Length < string2.Length ? string1.Length : string2.Length) - 1)
        .Any(x => string1.Substring(string1.Length - x) == string2.Substring(0, x));
```

`is_match` is `true` in this example.

---

A slightly simpler, but less efficient, solution:

```
bool is_match =
    Enumerable
        .Range(1, string1.Length)
        .Any(x => string2.StartsWith(string1.Substring(string1.Length - x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide code right now, but I can walk through one possible solution:

1. Split the strings on '/' to get the parts (let's call them "tokens")
2. Check if `string1` contains the first token of `string2`. Keep track of the positions.
3. Move forward in `string1`, check if the next token equals the second token of `string2`
4. Keep comparing tokens, if you keep matching and reach the end of either string you have a match

Answer (score 0):

Easy :

```cs
{
     string string1 =  "C:/GII/gii_db/DownTime/EMEA";
     string string2 = "DownTime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";
     string[] splitStr1 = string1.Split(new char[] { '/' });
     string[] splitStr2 = string2.Split(new char[] { '/' });

     if ((splitStr1[splitStr1.Length - 2] == splitStr2[0]) && (splitStr1[splitStr1.Length - 1] == splitStr2[1]))
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Matched");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool EndIsTheBegginingOf(this string s1, string s2)
    {
        for (int i = s1.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var part = s1.Substring(i);
            if (s2.StartsWith(part)) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var s1 = @"C:/GII/gii_db/DownTime/EMEA";
var s2 = @"DownTime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";
var res = s1.EndIsTheBegginingOf(s2); // true

s2 = @"DownT/ime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";
res = s1.EndIsTheBegginingOf(s2); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

From my POV you can do it with `string.Contains`.

You can ask if the `Downtime/EMEA` is in both strings.

Here is the following code, if I'm wrong correct me.

```
var string1 = @"C:/GII/gii_db/DownTime/EMEA";
var string2 = @"DownTime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";

if (!string1.Contains("/DownTime/EMEA") && string2.Contains("/DownTime/EMEA"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Matched");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matched");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Seems like you didnt't read that OP mentioned `I have tried with string.Contains() method but not successful..`

Comment: What happens if the text that needs to be matched varies in usage? This solution will only work if the OP is trying to match `/DownTime/EMEA` every single time.

Comment: @MattJones could give me an example pls I would like to test it

Comment: What happens if one string ends in `/Uptime/OMEO` and the other string starts with `/Uptime/OMEO`? Your code only works in one very specific case.

Comment: Its not a fixed string so i cannot decide what to match.

Comment: @Asma Yea I understand, but you could give the input  as string , and then check it with Contains. e.g. ``string.Contains(input)`` , but you will need to type the path manually

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want, you can try it

```
//find a string which is end with string1 and start with string2
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var string1 = @"C:/GII/gii_db/DownTime/EMEA";
            var string2 = @"DownTime/EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL/Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T.SQL";
            string result = "";

            int length = string1.Length;
            int index = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                string temp = string1.Substring(length - i - 1, index++);

                if (string2.StartsWith(temp))
                {
                    result = temp;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"result:{result}");

            ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I think your answer is the same as mine.

Comment: Yes, it is. I just provided a simple example, your answer is more clear. @dafie

Answer (score 0):

You could write some code that splits the two sequences into bigrams of the form 'xxxxxx/xxxxxx', where xxxxx is a sequence of letters and underscores. Then you could compare the matches found for each string. The following regex code matches what you want in both strings. It is then a matter of comparing all the matches found from all the strings you have:

```
(DownTime/EMEA)*/*(EMEA/APPS_GLOBAL)*/*(APPS_GLOBAL/Tables)*/*(Tables/XXG_CHUB_ADDRESS_T\.SQL)*/*
```

Supposing you have first split the strings into the format mentioned above, you should be good to go.